# Ad blocker detection for mobile browser

Tags: phpbb3, adblock

my curent ad blocker detection doesn't work for uc browser, yet it work on opera mini and pc browser.

How can i block uc browser who turn on their ad blocker?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Adsense, and use this code to detect adblocker in UC Browser.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  if( document.querySelectorAll && document.querySelectorAll('[data-adsbygoogle-status]').length==0 ) {
    alert('AdBlock detected');
  }
}, 3000);
```

Currently, I'm testing using UC Browser v10.10.5.809, and it works.

Comment: This does not work anymore with latest iPhone version... any ideas?